# Azure Devops SonarCloud Error: -Project not found. Please check the 'sonar.projectKey' and 'sonar.organization' properties, the 'SONAR_TOKEN'

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarcloud

We are using the Sonarcloud plugin in Azure DevOps. Suddenly, we get the following error in our build pipeline:

> ##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution ERROR: Project not found. Please check the 'sonar.projectKey' and 'sonar.organization'
> properties, the 'SONAR_TOKEN' environment variable, or contact the
> project administrator ERROR: ERROR: Error during SonarScanner
> execution ERROR: Project not found. Please check the
> 'sonar.projectKey' and 'sonar.organization' properties, the
> 'SONAR_TOKEN' environment variable, or contact the project
> administrator ERROR:
> ##[error]The SonarScanner did not complete successfully The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
> ##[error]09:51:19.094  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1 09:51:19.094  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
> ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/dotnet' failed with exit code 1

Authentication is done with *ServiceConnections* and the token verification is still valid. I also tried to use a new SonarCloud Authentication token for the ServiceConnection. We haven't changed anything in the infrastructure or on the *SonarCloud platform*, and it was working fine 5 days ago.

I tried to set `Administration / Permission / Execute Analysis` to "*Anyone*" (also checked all users) without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PAT (Personal Access Token) has expired.
Create one in Azure DevOps and add it `Administration / Organization settings / Azure DevOps connectivity management / New Personal Access Token`

Note: I had to `abandon` my Pull-Request and create a new one after using the new PAT.

I would like to see this more clearly indicated on the platform (e.g. by an info bar at the top of the platform)

Comment: There is currently no built-in functionality in DevOps to alert you that the PAT is about to expire. If you need such a feature, it's recommended that you could submit a feature request on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. It is suggested that you mark this answer, it will help others who have the same problem as you to know your solution.